# How to use data augmentation in Customdatagenerator of Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensor

I want to do these data augmentation but flow_from_dataframe cannot support except 1 & 3 channel image.

```
training_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
                              rotation_range=270,
                              width_shift_range=0.3,
                              height_shift_range=0.3,
                              brightness_range=[0.1,0.9],
                              shear_range=20,
                              zoom_range=0.35,
                              channel_shift_range=0.1,
                              horizontal_flip=True,
                              vertical_flip=True,
                              rescale=1/255,
                              validation_split=0.2
                               )
training_set_generator = training_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
    ,,,
    )
```

So I need to use data augmentation in customdatagenerator.

I consider that I should call def_data_augmentation in get_data for loop, but I dont know how to input augmented_data to X[i,]  and create corresponding label file.

My data is 8_channel .npy file and label file have .npy absolute path & label number

```
train_dir = r'C:\Labbb\mergeimage_npy\512512\npy\train'
params = {'dim': (512,512), 
          'batch_size': 1,
          'n_classes': 7, 
          'n_channels': 8,}
image_folders = ['image0', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image6', 'image7']  
label_folders = ['label0', 'label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4', 'label6', 'label7']  

class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, image_folders, label_folders, dir, dim=(512,512),  batch_size=1,n_classes=7,n_channels=8,shuffle=True):
        self.image_folders = image_folders
        self.label_folders = label_folders
        self.dir = dir
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.image_paths = []
        self.label_paths = []

        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.image_paths) / self.batch_size))  

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        batch_image_paths = self.image_paths[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_label_paths = self.label_paths[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch = zip(batch_image_paths, batch_label_paths)
        return self.get_data(batch)

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.image_paths = []
        self.label_paths = []
        #self.y_true = []
        for folder in self.image_folders:
            image_folder_path = os.path.join(self.dir, folder)
            image_files = os.listdir(image_folder_path)
            for file_name in image_files:
                self.image_paths.append(os.path.join(image_folder_path, file_name))
        for folder in self.label_folders:
            label_folder_path = os.path.join(self.dir, folder)
            label_files = os.listdir(label_folder_path)
            for file_name in label_files:
                self.label_paths.append(os.path.join(label_folder_path, file_name))
                
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.image_paths)
            np.random.shuffle(self.label_paths)

    def get_data(self, batch):
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.n_classes))
        
        for i, (image_path, label_path) in enumerate(batch):
            image = np.load(image_path)
            with open(label_path, 'r') as f:
                line = f.readline().strip()
                filepath, label = line.rsplit(' ', 1)
                label = int(label)
            label_one_hot = to_categorical(label, num_classes=self.n_classes)
            augmented_image = self.data_augmentation(image)

            X[i,] = augmented_image
            y[i,] = label_one_hot

        return X, y

    def data_augmentation(self, image):
        augmented_image = ... 
        ...
        return augmented_image

train_datagen = CustomDataGenerator(image_folders, label_folders, train_dir, **params, shuffle = True)
```

Comment: I think the solution lays in modifying only the function get_item in your custom generator, so inside you get the raw data then you apply your augmentation and finally combine them with assigning the original labels to the augmented data. 
Or your question was about how to apply these image augmentations on 8-channel data?